# Can mysql be used to constrain each row of a VARCHAR to have length equal to INT column in same row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in a mysql table that are set by user preference:

`custom_string VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL`

`items_per_row TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '5'`

EXAMPLE:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|             preferences              |
+--------------------------------------+
| id | custom_string | items_per_group |
+--------------------------------------+
|  1 |   TRINKETS    |        8        |
+--------------------------------------+
|  2 |               |        5        |
+--------------------------------------+
|  3 |    MYSTUFF    |        7        |
+--------------------------------------+
```

`items_per_row` is a required field. The `custom_string` field is optionally used to personalize the way grouped items in the list are displayed.

The user is able to update these preferences any time. Here is a crude example of how items might be displayed:

[image]

**I am wanting to find a way to constrain the length of each user's `custom_string` so that if it is not blank it must have a length that is exactly the same as the corresponding `items_per_group` value.**  I can easily validate the user input with both javascript and PHP and prevent the data from being entered into the database if it doesn't comply with this requirement, however, **is there a way to set this constraint within mysql so that an attempt to have an 'invalid' string would be rejected?**

Comment: Typically you would use check constraints to implement this.  But MySQL does not enforce these right now (though it does allow to define them, for some strange reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not implement `check` constraints.  With them, this would be easy:

```
alter table preferences add constraint chk_preferences_custom
    check (custom_string is null or length(custom_string) = items_per_group);
```

Your only option in MySQL is to use a trigger for this purpose.

In practice, it might be simpler to check at the application level when you insert/update `custom_string`.

Comment: It seems that a trigger would work for this purpose, however, given that it is simple enough to validate on the server side before even submitting the query, that will be the solution I will use for now.  I am considering migrating to PostgreSQL for this and future projects, anyway.